# APP Store not allowing me to select new build

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

I know this question has been asked many times, but the solution to those question are older. My problem is that I have uploaded app on app store and now its status is "Ready For Sale".

Now to update the screenshots I have to publish the new version as all things are locked by Apple and it is showing me following thing

> To make changes to the app name, category or privacy policy, create a new app version. All other changes will be immediately available on the App Store.

So I have created a new version. the previous version was 1.0.5 and now the new update is 1.0.6

I can see my new version under "All Build" section. I am unable to select the new version

**What I want:**

> ***I want to upload new screenshots. But I was unable to do so. As Apple has locked all things. Now to update screenshots I have came to know that to upload/updated new information I have to push a new update. So I created new build and uploaded it using Xcode. but Now I am unable to proceed. Please tell me how to send a new update and new app information.***

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about how to use a web site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; questions about app store policy should be directed to that app store's customer support.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new version in App Store Connect. Then you can select the new build, change screenshots and text for only that version.

Check the official guide with screenshots: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev480217e79